# Is there a maximum indentation at once setting for Uncrustify?

Tags: objective-c, code-formatting, uncrustify

I have a block of objective c code that looks like this

```
[paths enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * path, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop) {
    BOOL isDir;

    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir]) {
        ......
    }
}];
```

However, after passing through Uncrustify, it becomes

```
[paths enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * path, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop) {
        BOOL isDir;

        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir]) {
            ......
        }
    }];
```

Is there anyway to make Uncrustify collapse the two indents into one and preserve the formatting of the code?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue was fixed in Uncrustify 0.58